# Что учить. Wpf или WinForms?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Недавно завершил тему генерики в с# и начал задаваться вопросом  , что лучше изучать?
Последний ответ на этот вопрос дотирован 2017г. мало ли что поменялось?

Comment: Оба устарели. Учите MAUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

И то и другое, но зависит от задач.

**Windows Forms** - низкоуровневый UI, работающий напрямую с Windows, использует API GDI+ для отрисовки. Исползуется Дизайнер/C# для программирвоания интерфейса. Так как GDI+ не имеет нативной поддержки (полу)прозрачности, Winforms тоже имеет этот недостаток. Это и есть та самая причина, почему я ушел на WPF.

**WPF** - рисует себя с помощью DirectX, поддерживает (полу)прозрачность элементов на нативном уровне. Использует XAML разметку для интерфейса (очень слабо, но похоже на то как это делается в HTML). Куча функций для кастомизации UI элементов, стили, шаблоны и т.д. Основной используемый шаблон проектирования - MVVM. Чтобы освоить WPF и понять его мощь, нужно изучить: XAML, Привязки данных (Data Bindings, они кстати в Winforms тоже есть) и MVVM.

Представим, что например я знаком и с тем и с другим плюс-минус одинаково. Я предпочту WPF, потому что там решать задачи, связанные с красивым UI, анимациями и прочими примочками гораздо проще. Многие штуки, которые в винформах надо реализовывать за 300+ строк кода, в WPF доступны из коробки. Winforms же рассматриваю как хороший инструмент для обучения низкоуровневой работы с WinAPI и прочими прелестями операционной системы, но на постоянке я бы пользоваться не стал.

А еще есть современные UI-движки: **MAUI** и **Windows App SDK** например, они базируются на современном WinRT API операционной системы и красоты там ещё больше. Минус их в том, что они пока в активной разработке и сыроваты. Кстати, MAUI вообще кросплатформенный, можно и под Android на нём UI делать.